# __getLastResponse do not return XML

Tags: php, xml

I have the following problem: unable to retrieve XML response.
The response is good in php variable $lists, but when I try to get the XML form of response using _getLastResponse, no XML is shown.

The code is

```
<?php
    $url = "http://www.onlinekartago.ro/ReservationWSTest/Offer.asmx?WSDL";
    $user = 'KartagoTest';
    $pass = 'KartagoTestPassword';
    try {
        $client_K = new SoapClient($url, array('trace' => 1));
    } catch (SoapFault $exception) {        throw $exception;   }
    $params = array('user'=>array('UserName'=>$user, 'Password'=>$pass),'cultureID'=>1); 
    $lists=$client_K->GetBaseListsAll($params);
//  print_r($lists);
    echo "Response:\n".$client_K->__getLastResponse()."\n Print_r:";
?>
```

I tried also the 'TRUE" value for trace, but with the same result. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you echo out to the browser, you most likely need to view source. And for [`SoapClient::__getLastResponse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php) to return something you have to use the TRUE value for trace. Not just try, but you're required (which you do in your example, just making this clear).

Comment: I also tried what you proposed (comment try/catch) like this, no change.//try {
  $client_K = new SoapClient($url, array('trace' => 'TRUE'));
 //} catch (SoapFault $exception) {var_dump($exception->getTrace());}

Comment: I did not suggest try/catch, you must have misread me.

Comment: I tried also the _getLastRequest and what is shown at echo is not XML, it looks this way: KartagoTestKartagoTestPassword1

Comment: Yes, that's just a common error for beginners: you're not looking at the XML but at the XML that is interpreted as HTML and then displayed by your browser. That's a common mistake. See the first sentence of my first comment.

Comment: Can you believe it? I tested all above in Firefox, and when I tried it in IE is all shown fine, and in Firefox I finally found the XML using View page source.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Response:\n" . htmlentities(str_ireplace('><', ">\n<", $client->__getLastResponse())) . "\n";
```